# Can a dependent continue working after primary visa holder's leave is curtailed?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I am a UK tier 2 visa holder and am planning on leaving my job to return to the states. From my understanding the [UKBA allows me 60 additional days](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/370522/Tier_2_Migrant_Policy_Guidance_v0_6.pdf) after they finish processing that I have left my job. So I likely have closer to 90 days after I finish before I have to leave. My wife is working in the UK as a dependent on my visa and my son is enrolled in school. Can she continue to work, and he continue to attend school, until the final day that we have to leave or would they have to stop immediately after our leave is curtailed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wife is a T2 dependent and you are going to resign. Can she still work until you ultimately leave?

As a dependent, her status is wholly reliant upon yours.  Technically, she needs to advise her employer and stop working on your resignation date or the curtailment notice whichever happens first.  To do otherwise may jeopardize her employer's credibility with UKVI, and if her employer is ever audited, they may have problems.

In best practices, she should approach her employer as soon as she knows your resignation date and discuss it with them. This will help keep both her and her employer clean and allow the employer to get a reading from UKVI *if they want*.  There is no "requirement" to do this however.